# Angular 2 svg:circle fill attribute binding

Tags: angular, svg, geometry, fill

I am trying to bind the value of the fill attribute in an `<svg:circle>` element to my `color: string = "#cecece"` variable in my component. I have read many articles and tried different ways afterwards, however, noone was successful:

```
style="fill: {{color}}"

[style]="fill: color"

[style]="fill: 'color'"

[attr.style]="fill: color"

[attr.fill]="color"

[attr.style.fill]="color"

fill="{{color}}"
```

Is there some way of making this work? I am even thinking about the possibility that I have a problem somewhere else.

The way it usually works without angular binding is:
`<circle fill="#cecece"></circle>`

Comment: `<circle [attr.fill]="#cecece"></circle>` should work

Comment: Yes it does, but I need to bind the `color` controller variable to the fill. My fifth example should do it but it did not work.

Comment: Then use `<circle [attr.fill]="{{color}}"></circle>`

Comment: @Faisal You can use `[]` and `{{}}`  together

Comment: You mean Cannot? Didnt know that thanks

Comment: @Faisal Yes, that is. We cannot use them together

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
[attr.fill]="color"
```

or

```
attr.fill="{{color}}"
```

should work for you

Comment: Thanks, the second method works, but the first should too and it did not work.